# postgrey via systemctl doesn't create socket

Tags: postgrey

If I run it `/usr/sbin/postgrey` with parameteres it works as usual. If i use `/etc/init.d/postgrey restart` or `systemctl restart postgrey` - it doesn't.

It looks like it doesn't read `/etc/default/postgrey` at all, but how to debug this?
And if so, how to force it?

/etc/default/postgrey:

```
POSTGREY_OPTS="--unix /var/spool/postfix/postgrey/socket"
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the `/etc/default/postgrey` contents and the output of `systemctl --no-pager --full status postgrey` it will show the effective options used. The systemd unit (possibly generated to defer to the init script) or the init script should be more or less human-readable. Start with that and relevant logs.

Comment: @anx - half-edited - later I add status